# Parse json response using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json in C#

Tags: c#, json

I want to know how to parse JSON response using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json namespace.

Below is the API, I am hitting:

`https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/articles?author=epaga&page=0`

I want to read fields from this API such as `title and url`

Below is the code I am using

```
private const string URL = "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/articles";
private string URLParameters = "?author=epaga&page=0";

public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    List<string> rankModels = new List<string>();
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

    // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(URLParameters).Result;
    if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // How should I read and parse JSON fields from here
    }
}
```

`

Comment: The real answer here is to use a real json library like JSON.NET which is probably the most downloaded nuget package of all times with 978 million downloads as of today.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ReadFromJsonAsync with the following models

```
HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync(URLParameters);
if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
  return await res.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Article>();
}


public class Data
{
      public string title { get; set; }
      public string url { get; set; }
      public string author { get; set; }
      public int num_comments { get; set; }
      public object story_id { get; set; }
      public object story_title { get; set; }
      public object story_url { get; set; }
      public object parent_id { get; set; }
      public int created_at { get; set; }
}

public class Article
{
      public int page { get; set; }
      public int per_page { get; set; }
      public int total { get; set; }
      public int total_pages { get; set; }
      public List<Data> data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This only exists in .NET 5 and it deffinetly does not use System.Runtime.Serialization.Json

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Namespace used: System.Runtime.Serialization.Json

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/articles?author=epaga&page=0");
        string URLParameters = "?author=epaga&page=0";

        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(URLParameters).Result;

        string jsonString = string.Empty;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // How should I read and parse JSON fields from here
            jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }

        // Make a stream to read from.
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
        writer.Write(jsonString);
        writer.Flush();
        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        // Deserialize from the stream.
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer
            = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Article));

        Article articles = (Article)serializer.ReadObject(memoryStream);

        var page = articles.page;
        var perPage = articles.per_page;
        var total = articles.total;
        var totalPages = articles.total_pages;

        // Read data from the list
        foreach (var articleData in articles.data)
        {
            var title = articleData.title;
            var author = articleData.author;                
            var url = articleData.url;
            var numComments = articleData.num_comments;
            var storyId = articleData.story_id;
            var storyTitle = articleData.story_title;
            var storyUrl = articleData.story_url;
            var parentId = articleData.parent_id;
            var createdAt = articleData.created_at;
        }



    [DataContract()]
    public class Data
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string title { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string url { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string author { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int num_comments { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public object story_id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public object story_title { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public object story_url { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public object parent_id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int created_at { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract()]
    public class Article
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int page { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int per_page { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int total { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int total_pages { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<Data> data { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I really would suggest to use a library like json.Net, makes it all simpler ..

You can work with the XElement like this:

```
var jsonReader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json), new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
var xe = XElement.Load(jsonReader);
foreach (var data in xe.Descendants("data"))
{
  var title = data.Element("title").Value;
}
```

Comment: It makes no sense to work with an XElement when using json when you can just deserialize to a class

Comment: I just tired to answer the question .. "I want to know how to parse JSON response using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json namespace."

There always might be a reason ;)

Comment: in any case combining XML with json is not a good idea. They are simply water and oil.